# Missing extension when save image on paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

```
 image = PortfolioFileItem.find(107)  
 img_source = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/test/portfolio_file_items_final/original/1.jpg"
 image.picture_from_url(img_source)
 image.save(false)
```

image save DONE but missing extensionof image. this is sample image name saved:
 open-uri20110528-6779-fpiust-0.

Please help me solved problem. thanks

Comment: Whats the issue here? Can you explain more? DO you want the name to match the input name?

Comment: no. in here I need paperclip save type of image. ex: 1.jpg. but it saved missing type (jpg)

Comment: Oh you want it to have a .jpg extension?

Comment: yes. I want have a extension.

Comment: Hope the answer works for you, good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add an extension to paperclip add this line after has_attached_file as an option

```
:path => ":rails_root/public/:attachment/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

You can customize this path to fit your needs however you must have the `.:extension` at the end, the :extension is one of many values that can be used for interpolation.

See this [blog post](http://thewebfellas.com/blog/2008/11/2/goodbye-attachment_fu-hello-paperclip) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

If the actual file does not have an extension originally you can detect extension and add it before saving

```
  def before_save
    tempfile = data.queued_for_write[:original]
    unless tempfile.nil?
      extension = File.extname(tempfile.original_filename)
      if !extension || extension == ''
        mime = tempfile.content_type
        ext = Rack::Mime::MIME_TYPES.invert[mime]
        self.data.instance_write :file_name, "#{tempfile.original_filename}#{ext}"
      end
    end

    true
  end
```

Comment: thanks for this, I really needed this! users were renaming files and leaving off the extension so I needed a way to detect the extension from the content type